# get latest posts from wordpress blog based on tags and display them in base site

Tags: php, wordpress

this might be easy question for you but not for me as i am really new to wordpress, i have setup `Wordpress` in my site as blog(and i am quite happy with that),

**i want to** display some posts from my wordpress blog to my base site, i am looking around but its like headache as i have thousands of references and i am confused,

`i want to display posts from certain tags,`

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

I use a program called rss2html setup with a category parameter. Costs a few bucks, but you can do practically anything with it (or via one of the companion programs available at same site). I have used it tons of times passing a category, custom query, or other parameter to it using the config file.

If you choose to pick up a copy and have questions configuring, gimme a shout, I've done literally hundreds of them.

You can find the program I use here: [www.feedforall.com](http://www.feedforall.com)